# How to make webpack bundle my assets/image/ although i call them from a url, into the component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

Webpack is copying static `png,jpg,svg` files that are imported into each component file.
The file that hosts the image, it is fixed and the path is static.

The component file is like so:  **mycomponent.ts**

---

`import img from 'assets/img/aa.png`

`....   <img src={img} alt="" />`

Below is a  more  complicated  case.

1. import an image from a url : `import imgurl from ${url}`
2. use it into `<img src={imgurl} />`
3. and webpack, still, move the images into `static` folder!! (this is my goal)

**What i need webpack to do:**.

---

1. bundle the images from `assets/img` and move them into `static/img`, as if the images
   had been imported from `assets/img`, instead of url.
2. **so far webpack ignores the images that are imported from a **url**, **possibly because it cant find them**, during the build process**
3. but as i fake the `js & css` output with `publicPath`:  **config.output.publicPath = `http://www...`;**,
   similarly can it be done for the images ?

**snippet of bundling image, so far:**

---

```
// so, this changes copy the imported, into react components, images, into 
// static/media
// but it copies ONLY the images that are imported from `assets/img`
// it ignores if i import an image from a url e.g. import img from ${url}

function addMedia(config, outputPath){
  const media = {
   test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|png)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
    { 
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
      name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
      outputPath: 'static/media',
    }
  }
  ]
};
 config.module.rules.push( media );
}
```

So i wonder if there is a way to bundle/copy images from `assets/img` --> `static/media`, althougt into react file **i import them from a url** ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy images from `assets/img` to `static/media` like so:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "assets/img", to: "static/media" }
      ],
      options: {
        concurrency: 100,
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Documentation of `copy-webpack-plugin`: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/

Comment: hi Mario, thanks, i m aware of the copy-webpack-plugin. The difference is that the copy-webpack-plugin copies all the folder while the other functionality, copies only the images that are used into the files. Which in my case it would be usefull.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Without seeing more of your code, I can not imagine how this could work. Is seems like the import location is only resolved at runtime, so how can the compiler/bundler/plugin know at build time, which assets to copy?

Comment: yeah, maybe thats not possible, i cant think any other solution at the moment. But before i go to the `copy-webpack-plugin` i ll explore the conditional import, so to get the images from local at build time, and take the env.url at run time...we ll see.